# How fabricate object based on String list in Java?

Tags: java

I have string which is from external source. Based on this string I have to generate an object.
All object which I have to generated extend the same abstract base class. 
I have a list with relation "string" <-> "class".

My question is where is best way to do this generation and how?

1. I can make separate class with method with if-else. And invoke it in place where I need.
2. I can put it to this if-else direct in place where I need
3. I can put it to abstract class.
4. Add to abstract class `Map<String,Class>` and try to use reflection (but I don't know how)
5. something else?

---

```
abstract class Element { 
    abstract String getType();
}
class AElement extends Element{
    String getType(){return "A";}
}
class BElement extends Element{
    String getType(){return "B";}
}
class CElement extends Element{
    String getType(){return "C";}
}

class MyObject {
   Element element;
   MyObject(String text){
   //here I conscruct my object form string.
   String[] elem = text.split(";");
   this.element = someMethod(elem[3]);
}
```

I know that elem[3] will be texts "A", "B" and "C" and then I should create in method someMethod() respective AElement, BElement or CElement object.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more or question, perhaps with a small example. From what I understand know, the string you receive is the name of the class of the object you have to create. If this is correct, then reflection can be a solution, namely if _a priori_ you don't know all the possible types of objects you may have to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is a good solution. It'll abstract you from object creation techniques.

Inside the factory you can create instances via reflection like this:

```
public static YourAbstract createObject(String className) {
    try {
       Class c = Class.forName(className);
       YourAbstract newObject = (YourAbstract)c.newInstance();
       return newObject;
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // handle the way you need it ... e.g.: e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Have a look at this question: [Using reflection in Java to create a new instance with the reference variable type set to the new instance class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215843/using-reflection-in-java-to-create-a-new-instance-with-the-reference-variable-ty)

Or, in case all the classes are known to the factory, create some sort of map from config or something similar:

```
public class YourAbstractFactory {

    private static Map<String, Class> classez = new HashMap<String, Class>();

    public static YourAbstract initFactory(Map<String, Class> classes) {
        // initialize your map
        classez.putAll(classes);
    }

    public static YourAbstract initFactory(Collection<String> classes) {
        // initialize your map
        for(String className : classes) {
            try {
               Class c = Class.forName(className);
               classez.put(className, c);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               // handle the way you need it ... e.g.: e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static YourAbstract createObject(String className) {
        try {
           Class c = classez.get(className);
           YourAbstract newObject = (YourAbstract)c.newInstance();
           return newObject;
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // handle the way you need it ... e.g.: e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use the [Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html).

```
public static SomeObject createObject(String externalString){
 //construct the object(Have your If-else here)
 return someObject;
}
```

Comment: So, where this method put? In to abstract class or separated class

Comment: separate class. Possible `SomeObjectFactory`

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that is able to create the provided object, based on it's input.