# Returning Interface instead Class<Interface>

Tags: java, class, casting, classloader

I wrote my own classloader, which works with classes, which implements interface Plugin. But I can't   cast Class to Plugin. What's wrong?

```
public Plugin load(String pluginName, String pluginClassName) {
        SimpleClassLoader system = new SimpleClassLoader();
        system.setClassName(pluginClassName);
        Plugin aClass = null;
        try {
            aClass = (Plugin) system.loadClass(pluginRootDirectory + pluginName + "\\" + pluginClassName + ".class");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return aClass;
    }
```

> Error:(18, 47) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class cannot be converted to Plugin

I addition this is the main part of my SimpleClassLoader class which extends ClassLoader.

```
@Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        byte[] bytes;
        try {
            bytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(name).toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException();
        }
        return  defineClass(className, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }
```

Comment: whats the exception thrown

Comment: loadClass just loads the class. You then need to create a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
classloader.loadClass("myclass.class");
```

Is going to return you Class type object and not custom Plugin type.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new instance of the class.  Don't name your Plugin aClass since that's not what it is.

```
Class clazz = system.loadClass(
                   pluginRootDirectory + 
                   pluginName + "\\" + 
                   pluginClassName + ".class");

Plugin plugin = (Plugin) clazz.newInstance();
```

This creates the plugin using reflection.  SimpleClassLoader only turned a string into a class.  It doesn't give you the object you want to cast to a plugin.

See also [Using reflection in Java to create a new instance with the reference variable type set to the new instance class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215843/using-reflection-in-java-to-create-a-new-instance-with-the-reference-variable-ty) and if the plugin has an argument constructor see [Can I use Class.newInstance() with constructor arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234600/can-i-use-class-newinstance-with-constructor-arguments)

Comment: Ohh it  also gives me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: FirstClass cannot be cast to ru.Plugin

Comment: @jenius, Does FirstClass implement Plugin?

Comment: Yes. But it is external class

Answer (score 0):

With this

```
public Plugin load(String pluginName, String pluginClassName) {}
```

you will return object of type Plugin, to return type what extends Plugin you need to write

```
public Class<? extends Plugin> load(String pluginName, String pluginClassName) {}
```

Comment: That's all wonderfully generic and correct but on it's own it still wont get him a Plugin.  Take him the rest of the way.

Comment: @CandiedOrange He is writing classloader, so possibly he wants to load a Class with "load" method

Comment: I know about this decision, but it isn't what I need

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the main problem was that the same classloader loaded my class and interface which is implemented, as a result I can't cast. And we need to load Plugin Interface with other classloader.