# Instantiate object from class name as string

Tags: java, reflection

Let's say  have a class name as string.

```
String myClass = "com.whatever.MyClass";
```

How can I instantiate this class using reflection and have an object of type `MyClass` and not `Object`, without using code like this:

```
MyClass myObj = MyClass.class.cast(instance);
```

Basically I want to convert an instance of `Object` to `MyClass` without using `MyClass` in code and just by knowing the class name as string.

Comment: You can't. In order to assign it to a reference of type `MyClass`, you need to know what `MyClass` is at compile time.

Comment: And the only way to do it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215843/using-reflection-in-java-to-create-a-new-instance-with-the-reference-variable-ty

Comment: You could look at the factory pattern, putting them into some kind of string-indexed container and calling them up. That's how it's done in C++, but I don't know about Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of a class and run its methods without ever having to import the class in your code using reflection:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("com.whatever.MyClass");
Object instance = clazz.newInstance();  // or use the given instance
clazz.getMethod("myMethod").invoke(instance);
```