# How to use return of "Class.forName(String)" as a type for variable?

Tags: java, class, variables, types

How to use return of "Class.forName(String)" as a correct type for variable?
I mean, for example - if I am getting class using:

`Class.forName("java.lang.String");`

how to use it as "String" like:

```
String something = "text";
```

??
Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: I guess you want to create an instance using a `String s = "java.lang.String"` in your case ? See [Using reflection in Java to create a new instance with the reference variable type set to the new instance class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215843/using-reflection-in-java-to-create-a-new-instance-with-the-reference-variable-ty) to see if it match what you want

Comment: It's in the Javadoc of Class, e.g. `Class t = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread")`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks for comments. I want to do it without importing Class what I want to get using Class.forName(patth); Is it possible? I just need to use methods of this class :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to create a `String` instance using Reflexion.

```
String s = (String) Class.forName("java.lang.String")
                         .getConstructor(Class.forName("java.lang.String"))
                         .newInstance("Foo bar");
System.out.println(s);
```

This will recover a `Class` using [`Class.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-)

From this class, you get a specific constructor that accept a `Class<?>...` (0..N parameter) using [`Class.getConstructor(Class<?>...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-). And then you create the instance passing the paramter value using [`Constructor.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-).

This is not safe, you have a lof of exception to catch from this, but this will do it.

You can use directly `Class.newInstance` but it need to have an empty constructor available.

Answer (score 0):

Demo and few words, but I dont assume this have practical sense for You.
My goal is to give very basic background, more complicated answers arrive too.

```
Object instance = null;
try{ 
 Class clazz = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
// now here is String.class

  instance = clazz.newInstance();
  // empty String as Object
}catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After this code `instance` will have empty String (accessible as Object, not too useful) 
In general many thing can go wrong, maybe class have not no arguments public constructor etc

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()